If $R \to S$ is an $R$-algebra, then $S \otimes_R R[X_1, \ldots, X_m]/I \cong S[X_1,\ldots,X_m]/I$
Let $\varphi: R \to S$ be an $R$-algebra, and let $I$ be an ideal in $R[X_1, \ldots, X_m]$. I need to show that $$S \otimes_R R[X_1,\ldots,X_m]/I \cong S[X_1,\ldots,X_m]/I$$ as $R$-algebras. Here we view $I$ as an ideal in $S[X_1,\ldots,X_m]$ via the map $\varphi: R \to S$. My idea is as follows.
Let $\psi_0: S \times R[X_1,\ldots,X_m]/I \to S[X_1,\ldots,X_m]/I: (s,f+I) \mapsto sf+I$. Here we define $sf$ as being $f$ but with its coefficients pushed through $\varphi$ (e.g. $f_0(s_1, r_1X_1+I) = \varphi(r_1)s_1X_1+I$). This map, $f_0$, is $R$-bilinear (and well-defined), hence induces a map $$\psi:S\otimes_R R[X_1,\ldots,X_m]/I \to S[X_1,\ldots,X_m]/I$$ given at the elementary tensors as $\psi(s\otimes f+I)=sf+I$.
To show $\psi$ is an isomorphism, I though to construct an inverse, and I thought maybe $$\chi: S[X_1,\ldots,X_m]/I \to S\otimes_R R[X_1,\ldots,X_m]/I: f+I \mapsto 1\otimes f+I$$. If this is a well-defined map, it is clearly the inverse of $\psi$, but I don't know how to show it is well-defined.
I also don't fully understand the whole "viewing $I$ as an ideal in $S[X_1,\ldots,X_m]$" thing.
Can anyone confirm whether or not I am correct? And perhaps explain a bit more how this viewing $I$ in inside $S[X_1,\ldots,X_m]$ works? Thanks in advance!

I don't personally consider this a duplicate, though the overall question "show these are isomorphic" has surely occurred before; the OP's particular method is... particular, and there were some things they said worth addressing

@FShrike What would be the more "classical" approach then? Or differently, of which post is this one possibly a duplicate? The method I used is just using the universal property of the tensor product, namely that every bilinear map $M\times N \to P$ factors over $M\otimes_R N \to P$.


"I  also don't fully understand the whole "viewing $I$ as an ideal in $S[X_1,\ldots,X_m]$" thing."

$R\to S$ creates an extension of scalars ring morphism $R[X_\bullet]\to S[X_\bullet]$. When you say "with its coefficients pushed through $\phi$" this is formally what you are doing; you are applying the ring homomorphism $R[X_\bullet]\to S[X_\bullet]$. Now, given any ring morphism $f:A\to B$, $J$ any ideal of $A$, there is a natural way to view $J$ as an ideal in $B$; you consider $J^e=f(J)\cdot B$ the extension of $J$ along $f$. Warning: the $A$-module homomorphism $J\to J^e$ need not be injective, so you can't necessarily faithfully view $J$ as an ideal of $B$, it may well lose information.
This notion is not so mysterious; say $I=(X_1^2+X_3+a\cdot X_4+b\cdot X_5)$. Then $I^e\subset S[X_1,\cdots,X_m]$ would just be $(X_1^2+X_3+\phi(a)\cdot X_4+\phi(b)\cdot X_5)$. The concept is a good one. A more common notation for $I^e$ would be $I\cdot S[X_\bullet]$. The general rule here is that if $S$ is an $R$-algebra, module, then $S\otimes_R R/J\cong S/JS$ as rings/$S$-algebras/$R$-algebras, modules respectively.
So when you write $(s,f+I)\mapsto sf+I$, really you should write $(s,f+I)\mapsto sf+I^e$ if you want to be pedantic. You can see it is well-defined exactly by definition of $I^e$; if $h\in I$, $sh$ shall be in $I^e$.
Your proposed inverse is not well defined; $f\in S[X_\bullet]$ cannot naturally be viewed as an element of $R[X_\bullet]$, so what should $1\otimes f$ mean? Let me suggest the alternative; map $F(X_\bullet)=\sum_\alpha(c_\alpha\cdot X^\alpha_\bullet)$ to $\sum_\alpha (c_\alpha\otimes\overline{X^\alpha_\bullet})$ where I am lazily using multi-index notation; $X^\alpha_\bullet$ would stand for some generic monomial such as $X_1 X_2^3 X_3^7$. The overline indicates I apply the quotient $R[X_\bullet]\to R[X_\bullet]/I$. This makes a ring map $S[X_\bullet]\to S\otimes_R R[X_\bullet]/I$, and composing with your forward map $\psi$ clearly gives the quotient map $S[X_\bullet]\to S[X_\bullet]/I^e$. I leave it to you to check this induces a genuine inverse to $\psi$. The definition of $I^e$ is important for that! You have to check my map kills $I^e$ and thus factors through the quotient, yielding something $S[X_\bullet]/I^e\to S\otimes_R R[X_\bullet]/I$.
In my opinion, a better way to see this is by juggling universal properties. You must show that maps $S\to T$ and $R[X_\bullet]/I\to T$ which both agree on $R$ uniquely, and naturally (in the commutative ring $T$) correspond with ring maps $S[X_\bullet]/I^e\to T$.

So to recap: viewing $I$ as an ideal inside $S[X_1,\ldots,X_m]$ we basically also just "replace" the coefficients of the polynomials in $I$ by their image under $\varphi$? As for the inverse, thanks! I didn't consider just mapping the 'basic' elements $s X_1^{i_1}\ldots X_m^{i_m}$ to the tuple $(s,X_1^{i_1}\ldots X_m^{i_m})$. At least, this is what you mean, right? [[modulo the ideal but I'm a bit lazy right now]]

@soggycornflakes Yes, that is what I mean. You can split the basic elements into (element of S) tensor (basic monomial). We do basically just replace coefficients, but it is important to remember we also multiply by all elements of $S$. Which, mind, might not all come from $R$, so we do have to do this. $\varphi(I)$ might not be an ideal if $\varphi$ isn't surjective, but certainly $\varphi(I)\cdot S[X_\bullet]$ is.

It is against the site policy to post answers to duplicate questions. Better invest some time to mark it as a duplicate.

@MartinBrandenburg I am well aware of the site policy. Did you see my comment about why I answered this anyway? I don't consider this an exact duplicate of any existing post I found
